# Linked Lists in C++ without a pointer to the Node class

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, infinite-loop

As specified in the title above, I am trying to program a linked list in C++ without a pointer to the Node class, and am instead directly using the object belonging to the node class. This is a method in the Linked List class I've written to display the data elements in the entire linked list:

```
void display(){                          
        Node t = head;
        while (t.link!=nullptr){
            cout<<t.data<<endl;
            t = *head.link;
       }
```

This prints the fisrt instance of t.data infinitely. How do I progress to the next head ? (PS: I am pretty new to implementation of linked lists in C++. There's a high chance I've made an obvious mistake. Also new to stackoverflow - like I've never asked a question before)

Below is the entire code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
    int data;
    Node *link;
};


class LinkedList: public Node {
    private: Node head;                    
    public:

    LinkedList(int a) {                      
         head.data=a;
         head.link=nullptr;
}

    void insert (int data) {                 
         Node t;              
         t.data=data;                        
         t.link = &head;                      
         head = t;                            
     }

    void display(){                          
        Node t = head;
        while (t.link!=nullptr){
            cout<<t.data<<endl;
            t = *head.link;
        }

     }
  };

int main() {
     LinkedList obj(20);          
     obj.insert(30);
     obj.insert(40);
    obj.display();
 }
```

Comment: `class LinkedList: public Node` is clearly wrong. Remove the inheritance, there is no reason for a linked list to inherit from the nodes that comprise it. Plus in my opinion your linked list class should have a pointer to a node. Your way you cannot have a list of length zero, every list has at least one node, which seems strange.

Comment: *"without a pointer to the Node class"*: well you already have one in your `Node` class: `Node *link;`. Do you really want a linked list without using pointers, even without `Node *link`, or what are you asking here?

Comment: The way to progress is: stop, go back, remove "without pointers" from your list of requirements, and continue from there.

Comment: Can't you just use `std::list`(doubly linked) or `std::forward_list`(singly linked)?

Comment: @john "your linked list class should have a pointer to a node" could you please clarify what you mean by this? thanks

Comment: @Red.Wave the whole point of the code is to understand how linked lists work. Using inbuilt methods would destroy the purpose.

Comment: @trincot I wanted the head node (or any other node) to not be a pointer to the Node class, but instead an object of the Node class

Comment: Yes, but every `link` is a pointer to the Node class, so it really is the same structure, except that you seem to prefer that your variables are of type `Node` and not `Node *`. Also in the classical way, the nodes of a linked list are of the type `Node`, but they are in practice referenced by pointers, mostly because pointers take less space for a local variable, than taking a copy of the node itself into a local variable -- which is what you want to do.

Comment: @EclipsedProgram I mean as trincot has answered below.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `insert` method:

```cpp
void insert (int data) {                 
     Node t;              
     t.data=data;                        
     t.link = &head;                      
     head = t;                            
}
```

You never allocate any memory here. You simply overwrite the contents
of `head` with the values written into the temporary variable `t`.
So after calling `insert`, `head.link` will end up pointing to `head` (itself),
which is why you get the infinite loop.

Let's look at your `display` function:

```cpp
void display(){                          
    Node t = head;
    while (t.link!=nullptr){
        cout<<t.data<<endl;
        t = *head.link;
    }
}
```

Every loop iteration sets `t` to the same value: `head.link`, which is the second element. This loop will never finish (if you have more than one element).

The demo here is one way of how you could fix these issues:
https://godbolt.org/z/v3bsoMvE7

Happy coding :).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this really should be done with pointers all the way, but I understand you want to see how you would do it without a pointer to a list. Still, you'll understand that the nodes themselves are still linked with a `link` pointer, so it's not that you got rid of pointers -- just the first pointer to the linked list.

The core problem with your implementation is that in `insert` you just overwrite the contents of `head`, which now has a `link` pointer to `&head` -- which is a self-reference. You really need to allocate new nodes, using `new`.

It is also counter intuitive that your linked list can only be created with at least one node. It cannot be a linked list with zero entries. To work around this (and allow zero entries), you could for instance treat the initial node (the linked list instance) as a *sentinel* node, i.e. a node whose value is discarded, and just serves to link to the real first node of the list, if any.

If you want to avoid the `->` syntax, then give your `Node` class a constructor -- overloaded to take values for its `data` and `link` members.

Here is how that would look:

```
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *link = nullptr;
    // add constructors
    Node(int data, Node *link) : data(data), link(link) {} 
    Node(int data) : data(data) {}
    Node() {}
};

class LinkedList: public Node {
// No private members. Just rely on inherited link field
public:
    void insert (int data) {                 
        link = new Node(data, link); // Use the power of the constructor
    }

    void display(){                          
        Node t = *this; // Copy of sentinel node
        while (t.link) {
            t = *t.link; // First move forward (we don't print sentinel)
            cout << t.data << " ";
        }
        cout << "null\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList obj; // Don't provide value: list can be empty
    obj.insert(20);
    obj.insert(30);
    obj.insert(40);
    obj.display();
}
```

For correct memory management you should also include a destructor to clean up allocated nodes.